# Retornar o valor de data selecionada no datapicker em uma variável

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, data

Boa tarde comunidade, primeira pergunta aqui. Tenho um datepicker fixo em uma div no meu código, não é um input!! e Eu não estou conseguindo pegar o valor selecionado e armazenar uma variável pois preciso posteriormente utiliza-lo em uma consulta no banco de dados.

var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );

Este é o código que esta na documentação, porém quando aplico no meu código não retorna na variável.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lava - Jato</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        maxDate: "+1w",
        minDate: 0,
        weekHeader: "W",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
        var currentDate = $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        }
    });
    });

</script>
<div id="cards">
      <div class="datepicker"></div>
            <h1> Data do Agendamento:<?php echo $currentDate;?></h1>
</div>
```

Estou fazendo algo de errado no meu código ? pois retorna a seguinte mensagem na minha pag. Warning: Undefined variable $currentDate in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto\Pages\conc-agendamento\conc-agendamento.php on line 77

Comment: `onSelect: function (dateText)`  a data selecionada vem na variável "dateText"

Comment: Boa tarde Ricardo, continua com o erro.
 Warning: Undefined variable $dateText in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto\Pages\conc-agendamento\conc-agendamento.php on line 77

Comment: essa variável só vale dentro da função associada ao `onSelect`

Comment: Está em PHP 7 ou 7+ certo? Esse erro é porque a variavel está vazia. Teria de ficar: `<?php if (isset($dateText)) { echo $dateText;};?>` Para atualizar a data cada vez que alguem ''pica'' uma data nova terá de usar javascript

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está a funcionar, o problema é quando faz o load ao document `(document.ready)` não há data selecionda, e então o erro que está vendo é do PHP porque a variavel está vazia. Terá de ficar

```
 <?php
      if (isset($dateText)) 
      { 
          echo $dateText;
      }
;?>
```

O que fiz foi adicionar uma linha de JS que atualiza o `<span>` com a data selecionada.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        maxDate: "+1w",
        minDate: 0,
        weekHeader: "W",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
        var currentDate = $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        $('#cards span').text(currentDate);
        }
    });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lava - Jato</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="cards">
      <div class="datepicker"></div>
            <h1> Data do Agendamento: <span></span></h1>
</div>
```